# How to see and access unsynced folders in Cloud storage service?

Tags: sync, dropbox, cloud-storage

I have very little disk space. I'd like to store rarely used files in the cloud and not on my own computer but still have access to them. I want only a few folders on my hard drive and the rest should be downloaded on demand, edited, synced back to the cloud and then deleted from my hard drive.

I used Dropbox, Google Drive, and OneDrive, but all of them only allow me to choose which folders to synchronize. Any other, not chosen folders can't be seen in cloud service directory. I want them to be seen in the cloud directory but not stored on my hard drive, something like network resource.

Is there any cloud service with functionality like that?

Comment: Google Docs has something close to this. Any document created with Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides shouldn't take up any space on your computer.